# Swap two numbers in pascal

Tags: pascal

I'm trying to swap two values but I'm getting a `Warning: Local variable "temp" does not seem to be initialized`. I want to do it similar as how I've done it. I'm compiling it from the command line with `fpc Main.pas`. I've tried initializing the temp variable to 0, but it still says `Fatal: there were 3 errors compiling module, stopping`.

'Main.pas'

```
Program Main;

procedure Main();
var
  n1, n2: Integer;
begin
  n1 := 5;
  n2 := 10;
  Swap(@n1, @n2);
  writeln('n1 = ', n1);
  writeln('n2 = ', n2);
end;

BEGIN
  Main();
END.
```

'Number.pas'

```
unit Number;

interface

type
  IntPtr = ^Integer;

procedure Swap(n1, n2: IntPtr);

implementation

procedure Swap(n1, n2: IntPtr);
var
  temp: Integer;
begin
  temp = n1^;
  n1^ = n2^;
  n2^ = temp;
end;

end.
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `:=` instead of `=`?

Comment: that did it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already discovered, you mixed up the assignment (`:=`) and equality (`=`) operators. Thus,

```
procedure Swap(A, B: PInteger);
var
  Temp: Integer;
begin
  Temp := A^;
  A^ := B^;
  B^ := Temp;
end;
```

where `PInteger` is defined as `^Integer`, does the job:

```
Swap(@Val1, @Val2); // swaps integers Val1 and Val2
```

However, I suggest you do this slightly differently:

```
procedure Swap(var A, B: Integer);
var
  Temp: Integer;
begin
  Temp := A;
  A := B;
  B := Temp;
end;
```

Using a `var` parameter is more idiomatic and it allows you to write simply

```
Swap(Val1, Val2); // swaps integers Val1 and Val2
```

and it also gives you a bit more type safety.